# CircleCI job using Ansible : Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, paramiko, circleci

I'm working on a CircleCi job running a configuration on an EC2 instance. The problem is that the ansible could not run the configuration and is still running in a loop on this **error** :

```
PLAY [configuration play]
******************************************************

TASK [wait 600 seconds for target connection to become reachable/usable] *******

Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner

buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline

buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 607, in _read_timeout

x = self.__socket.recv(128)

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2039, in run

self._check_banner()

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2215, in _check_banner

raise SSHException(

paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner

buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline

buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 609, in _read_timeout

raise EOFError()

EOFError
```

....

```
fatal: [ec2-18-237-14-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 600, "msg": "timed out waiting for ping module test success: Error reading SSH protocol banner"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ec2-18-237-14-97.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Circle-Ci job :**

```
  configure-infrastructure:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.7-alpine3.11
    steps:
      - checkout       
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints: ["bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla:bla"]
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/

      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
              apk add --update tar gzip ansible
              pip install awscli
      - run:
          name: Configure server
          command: |
            cat ./.circleci/ansible/inventory.txt
            export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
            export RECORD_HOST_KEYS=True
            ansible-playbook -i ./.circleci/ansible/inventory.txt ./.circleci/ansible/configure-server.yml
      - destroy-environment
```

**.circleci/ansible/configure-server.yml**

```
---
- name: configuration play
  hosts: web
  user: ubuntu
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
    - ansible_host_key_checking: false
    - ansible_stdout_callback: yaml
  pre_tasks:
    - name: wait 600 seconds for target connection to become reachable/usable
      ansible.builtin.wait_for_connection:
        delay: 0
        timeout: 600
    - name: install python for Ansible.
      become: true
      raw: test -e /usr/bin/python3 || (apt -y update && apt install -y python3)
      changed_when: false
  roles: 
   - configure-server
```

**roles/configure-server/tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: "Update apt packages"
  become: true
  apt:
    update_cache: yes

- name: "Remove dependencies that are no longer required"
  become: true
  apt:
    autoremove: yes

- name: "Install npm and nodejs"
  become: true
  apt:
    name: ["npm", "nodejs"]
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes

- name: "Install pm2"
  become: true
  npm:
    name: pm2
    global: yes
    production: yes
    state: present
```

I have already added my key pair to the Circle project settings, obtained the fingerprints and added it to the job configuration ([bla:bla.....]).

I can connect to the Ec2 instance using ssh without any problems.

More details :

```
ImageId: ami-0d70546e43a941d70 
region: us-west-2
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You now have to understand why you think you can connect without any problems via ssh while Ansible is telling you the exact opposite when running from circleci infrastructure (i.e. `connection reset by peer`. Looking at your sshd log on ec2 side might help. Note: this is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on SO, try https://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

it's stucked with me also, finally i fixed it:-

```
  configure-infrastructure:
    docker:
      # - image: python:3.7-alpine3.11
      - image: python:3.9.16
    
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "6b:7d:b7:2c:5b:49:34:cb:34:ab:93:36:47:19:2b:73"
      - run:
          name: Install dependenciess
          command: |
            # apk add --update ansible 
            apt-get update -y
            apt install ansible -y
            which ansible
      - run:
          name: Configure server
          command: |
            cd .circleci/ansible
            cat ./inventory
            ansible-playbook -i inventory configure-server.yml
```